# mathematical puzzle whose solution seems to contradict its own hypotheses

Tags: mathematics

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYFHMD_ja7c) shows a mathematical puzzle that had me quite baffled, and at the moment I seem to disagree with the solution that is proposed as unique.

> A leaf is torn from a paperback novel. The sum of the numbers on the remaining pages is 15000. What are the page numbers on the torn leaf.
>
> (Problem 1, [1994 India Regional Math Olympiad](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Ermo/papers/rmo/rmo-1994.pdf))

The 'inevitable' assumption I think one needs to make, which is also made in the video, is that pages are numbered with consecutive integers starting at $1$ and ending at $N$ , *without skipping any number*.
Unlike I previously thought, it is *not* necessary to assume that *all* sheets have numbers on both sides.
However, if it's true that no numbers *and no sheet sides* are skipped from the numbering in between $1$ and $N$, it is necessary to assume that the *only* possible missing page numbers are the left side one on the first numbered page (which would then start at $1$ on its right side), or the right side one on the last numbered page (which would then end at $N$ on its left side).
If the torn off sheet had no numbering on either side, no numbers would be subtracted from the sum, and, as shown later, that would be incompatible with the $15000$ figure.

I approached this puzzle in a slightly different way compared to the video.

Here is my solution.

> As mentioned, $N$ is the last and highest page number in the book, the first and smallest being $1$.
>  If no sheet were torn off, the sum of all page numbers would be the known formula $\frac {N(N+1)} 2$.
>  This expression cannot be equal to 15000 for any positive integer $N$, thus the torn off page must have at least one page number on it.
>
> The sheet that is torn off cannot be the first or the last numbered one, either, regardless of whether it is numbered only on one side or both.
>  This can be shown by proving (e.g. numerically) that the following equation:
>  $\frac {N(N+1)} 2 - S = 15000$
>  has no positive integer solution for $N$ for any of the 4 mentioned cases: $S = \{1, 1+2, N-1+N, N\}$.
>
> Let $x$ be the number on the *left* side of the sheet that is torn off. As shown, that cannot be the first numbered sheet. Thus $x \ge 2$.
>  $x+1$ is then the number on the right side of the sheet that is torn off. As shown, that cannot be the last numbered sheet. Thus $x+1 \le N-1$, i.e. $x \le N-2$.
>
> Once the sheet is torn off, $x+x+1$ is removed from the sum, hence:
>  $15000 = \frac {N(N+1)} 2 - x - x - 1$
>  Solving for $x$:
>  $x = \frac {N^2+N-30002} 4$
>
> Applying the two boundary conditions on $x$, i.e. $2 \le x \le N-2$.
>
> $x \ge 2$
>  $\frac {N^2+N-30002} 4 \ge 2$
>  Knowing that $N$ is a positive integer, the only valid solution is:
>  $N \ge 173$
>
> $x \le N-2$
>  $\frac {N^2+N-30002} 4 \ge N-2$
>  Knowing that $N$ is a positive integer, the only valid solution is:
>  $N \le 174$
>
> So we know that $N = 173$ or $N = 174$.
>
> If $N = 173$:
>  $x = \frac {N^2+N-30002} 4 = 25$
>  The sheet that is torn off is the one numbered 25 on the left side, 26 on the right side.
>  This means that all odd pages appear on left sides, all even pages on right sides.
>  In turn, this means that the last numbered sheet has $173$ on the left side and is not numbered on the right side.
>  The first numbered sheet instead is numbered on both sides, $1,2$.
>  All of this is consistent with the hypotheses, there is no contradiction, so this solution appears to be valid.
>
> If $N = 174$:
>  $x = \frac {N^2+N-30002} 4 = 112$
>  The page that is torn off is the one numbered 112 on the left side, 113 on the right side.
>  This means that all even pages appear on left sides, all odd pages on right sides.
>  In turn, this means that the last numbered sheet has $174$ on the left side and is not numbered on the right side.
>  The first numbered sheet is also numbered only on one side side, the right one, with $1$.
>  Again, no contradiction with any of the hypotheses, so this solution appears to be valid, too.

Just to check, I made an Excel sheet with the list of page numbers and alternating left/right labels, as per the two solutions, and removed in each case the appropriate pair of consecutive pages: the sums are both $15000$.

First issue: is it OK to assign a problem that has two possible solutions (assuming that only one is then scored as correct)?

Second issue: see 4:04 and 4:30 in the video.
In essence, only solution $N = 173$ is considered valid, based on the further assumption that if a page number is missing, it can be *necessarily only from the last page*.
My impression is that the video reaches only one solution as an effect of unnecessary assumptions.

**Can you see any mistake in my reasoning?

Do you think the solution shown by the video is the only valid one, or are both solutions indeed possible, as I concluded, given the rather vague (or say 'open') formulation of the problem?**

Comment: *"This, together with the fact that the first sheet has '1' on its left side, implies that the last sheet has an even number on its right side, and consequently, the total number of pages is even"*

I think this is where you go wrong. I have read books that do end on the 'left' side of the last sheet of paper, with the 'right' side ending up blank (or unumbered, being the about the author page, or ads for other books). In fact, the book I just grabbed to confirm this ends on page 447, but also starts on page 9 so that's fun in the context of this puzzle.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, you're right - I am editing the post. See the note I added to the top.

Comment: There are two assumptions that must be made in order for this to be solvable. The first is that pages are numbered in standard form, each sheet being numbered $k,k+1$ with $k$ odd. This reasonable assumption excludes the solution with $k=112$. The second is that all pages are numbered. While most books will have some pages unnumbered (citation required), this assumption is necessary for the problem to have any logical solution.

Comment: Hi Daniel, actually, some comment in the youtube video webpage say that the standard form of book numbering is with 1 starting on the *right* side of the first numbered sheet (something like 'folio'). But OK, even if that is no object, I think I proved here that it is *not* necessary to introduce that constraint to have a valid solution. If you can show that my solution with $N=174$ is impossible when no assumptions are made on where number $1$ is, I am keen to see the proof. Thanks

Comment: To be clear(er): this being a mathematical problem from a mathematical competition, it should not be necessary to know any technical details about how real books are numbered, so it is immaterial where $1$ is in 'most' books (plus indeed it's not a universal or physical necessity). So, while the assumption that pages are numbered by consecutive integers starting at $1$ and ending at $N$ is probably inevitable, there is no justification or need to introduce any additional arbitrary constraints. Thus the only option is to work from that and find *all* valid solutions, as I think I did.

Comment: Even numbers on the left, odd numbers on the right is standard. This refers to the two pages (on separate sheets) that an open book displays. This has odd numbers on the front of each sheet. See Wikipedia [page numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_numbering).

Comment: As to this being from a competition, I did not watch the video. My comments were based on this being an isolated puzzle. As a puzzle that relies on the common page numbering system to provide a unique answer, this question does not belong in such competitions.

Comment: @DanielMathias : I fully agree. My impression is that the problem is in itself very poorly formulated, because it requires people to make assumptions about the page numbering, and then leads to further complications regarding which pages have only one numbered side. If we were talking about a physical object with immutable properties that one needs to know, it might be OK to expect people to know and assume those, but a book in principle can be numbered in any crazy and arbitrary way, so for a *pure mathematics* problem nothing should be left open to interpretation.